# Autolayout issue when showing the dropdown table

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

In my app i want to show a dropdown table, after clicking the text field. But it is not working good.

```
tableViewOne.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in

                let superViewOriginY: CGFloat = (textField.superview?.frame.origin.y)!
                let textFieldMaxY: CGFloat = textField.frame.maxY
                let navigationHeight: CGFloat = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height
                let textFieldHeight = textField.frame.height
                let tableViewOneTopPsition = superViewOriginY + textFieldMaxY + navigationHeight + textFieldHeight

                make.top.equalTo(tableViewOneTopPsition)
                make.left.equalTo(15)
                make.right.equalTo(-15)
                make.height.equalTo(0)
            }
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            UIView .animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                self.tableViewOne.snp.updateConstraints({ (make) -> Void in
                    make.height.equalTo(170)
                })
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
```

By writting this code, it works for iphone 11 Max simulator. But for iphone 8 plus simulator there is some gap between the textfield and the table view.` In this following images there are textfields inside the stackview.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDUkw.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkQXd.png

```
   First one image is the iphone 11max pro image 
   and the second one is the iphone 8 plus image
```

if i will write

```
 make.top.equalTo(textFieldMaxY)
```

```
the i will be
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmNNe.jpg

Please help me to overcome the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line

```
tableViewOne.snp.updateConstraints { (make) in

    make.top.equalTo(textField.snp.bottom).offset(5)
    make.left.equalTo(15)
    make.right.equalTo(-15)
    make.height.equalTo(0)
 }

            UIView .animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
                self.tableViewOne.snp.updateConstraints({ (make) -> Void in
                    make.height.equalTo(170)
                })
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Hi @Jawad after adding the code, i am getting error like -  Fatal error: Updated constraint could not find existing matching constraint to update:

Comment: can you share demo project to look into ?

Comment: whats view herarichy of table and textfield ?

Comment: there is a scrollview , inside of this a view is there and inside of this the stackview .

Comment: tableView and textField are in ?

Comment: TextFields are  in the stackview. and  adding the tableview programetically .like -  self.view.addSubview(tableViewOne)

Comment: and where is stack ending ?

Comment: stack has a height of 265. there are two stackview- one is for player2 and anothe one is for player3

Comment: yes all text fields are in stackview. the "player2" "player3" and more labels are not inside the stackview.

Comment: `insertArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView, 
                        at stackIndex: Int)`.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview/1616237-insertarrangedsubview

Comment: insert tableview after that field ... give it just height constraint .... and your stack have distribution ... fill propotionally

Comment: But the tableview should be above the stackview not inside the stackview.

Comment: why is it so ? why you want it above ?

Comment: please look into the image. it should be like this

Comment: means the text fields inside the stackview will not change their position.

Comment: so that means tableview will hide some fields ?

Comment: then you need to calculate ... remove this line  `let textFieldHeight = textField.frame.height`

Comment: this above code is working for iphone11 max pro. But it is not working in iphone 8 plus. you can see first two images.

Comment: `topSafeArea = view.safeAreaInsets.top` ... add this to calculation ... hopefully resolve your issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214659/discussion-between-jawadali-and-tapan-raut).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your constraints are correct. To fix the bug you specify you can change `topAnchor` constraint of the `tableViewOne` to `bottomAnchor` of `textField`. Don't calculate the frame to give the `topAnchor`, instead give the constraint to the adjutant views.

```swift
tableViewOne.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textField.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

When adding this remove this line:

```swift
make.top.equalTo(tableViewOneTopPsition)
```

Comment: Yes i added this code also. but the table view disappears.  is it happening for stackview?

Comment: You need to remove the other constraint.

Comment: There is no other constraints. "Leading" and "Tralling" spaces to super view- 15. height is  265. top space to the label 10. also stackview Allignment is "fill" , distribution is "fill equally" and spacing is 10.

Comment: @TapanRaut I've added the constraint you need to remove in my answer.

Comment: if i will remove the constrain, then how is it work? some minimum constraint should required.

Comment: @TapanRaut Add the 1 I've provided to add instead of the 1 I've provided to remove.